# Changing default settings for sharepoint access request

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-2007, moss

I am working with office 365 SharePoint site. When any user requested access for page, am receiving mail which contain ACCEPT and DECLINE buttons. When I grant access by default user is getting "Edit" access. How can I change this default access from "Edit" to "READ"?

Comment: Which of the two versions of SharePoint are you using - are you using both 2013 and 2007?

Comment: I am using office 365

Comment: Hi All, pls help me here..